# Opening an external file while running Python in IDLE from Notepad++

Tags: python, file, import, notepad++

I have two files, both on my Desktop:

#### sotest.py

```py
print 'Hello world'
```

#### sotest2.py

```py
foo = open ('sotest.py', 'r')
```

I'm running Python out of Notepad++ as follows (from [Use IDLE to launch script using the full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598426/use-idle-to-launch-script-using-the-full-file-path)):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Running sotest2.py returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doncherry\Desktop\sotest2.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo = open ('sotest.py', 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sotest.py'
```

When running the same file out of Pyhton's IDLE, it runs without errors. If I change sotest2.py to the following, it works out of Notepad++ without problems.

```py
import sotest
```

Which part of my configuration do I need to change to make the opening work? I'd prefer to change some setting in Notepad++ rather than adding code to each of my Python files.

Comment: Try to print out your working directory (os.getcwd()). Most likely it is set to a path where notepad++ starts which is not your desktop

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy: Correct, it returns `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++`. Can I pass the working directory to IDLE from Notepad++?

Comment: If you remove the -r from the command, it starts in the correct directory, but then it doesn't run the script automatically...

Comment: @ChimeraObscura: So ... then it just opens an empty IDLE? How would I get the script running from there?

Comment: I'm using the following command in notepad++, and it opens the current file in idle's editor: `E:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Answer (score 0):

`import sotest` works because it searches `sotest` module in `sys.path` and the `sotest2.py`'s directory is added to `sys.path` if you run `sotest2.py` as a script. If `sotest2.py` and `sotest.py` were in different directories then unless something else put `sotest.py`'s directory into pythonpath then `import sotest` inside `sotest2.py` would fail.

To open sotest.py inside sotest2.py as a file you could specify its absolute path. Assuming they are in the same directory you could find it automatically:

```
# in sotest2.py:
import os

scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'sotest.py')
with open(path) as sotest_file:
     text = sotest_file.read()
```